# Lubuntu sound settings from sound applet

Tags: sound, lubuntu, pulseaudio, configuration, pavucontrol

I configured a Lubuntu 16.04 system for a friend. While configuring we wanted to change sound settings. We clicked on the Lubuntu sound applet and on sound settings but nothing opened. I remeber that on some system I saw that pavucontrol opens this way. So we tried to install pavucontrol with pulseaudio but both was already installed. We started pavucontrol from terminal and it works. But terminal is absolutely no option for my friend. What is the problem with the applet and how to solve it?

EDIT:
An answer describes a solution where the audio indicator is replaced by an audio applet. This solution works but I'm interested why the indicator doesn't work as expected and why I need this workaround.

Comment: Did you remove the sound notification icon and/or enable the sound INDICATOR icon?

Comment: The icon is there. I didn't do anything to it. I can change the volume. But under the volume is a button for sound settings. As I remember this should open pavucontrol but nothing happens when clicked.

Comment: "under the volume"?

Comment: When I click on the sound applet a volume bar opens. Underneath the volume bar is the button

Comment: Sounds like you're using the INDICATOR sound and not the icon as I mentioned before.

Comment: http://lh4.ggpht.com/_1QSDkzYY2vc/S6KddPZ9WWI/AAAAAAAAAnk/gmvV4cdXgfg/s2000/SS_Selection_008.png

Comment: It looks like in the link. There is a volume bar and a button for sound settings. But a click on the button doesn't work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to get the Lubuntu/lxde sound icon in panel, as it's the default config of a fresh install, right click on the panel and select "add elements to the panel".

In this window you will select the"Add" button and search for the "volume control" applet.

Put it in any part of the panel you want and after this you can right click the icon and select "configuration" which will open alsamixergui or pavucontrol if you installed it.

[image]

You can then right click the notification INDICATOR area and disable the sound menu indicator.

[image]

Comment: I try it next time I'm there. But do you know why the default doesn't work though there is sound settings button?

Comment: As I said the icon already there and I can change the volume but I can't open pavucontrol

Comment: As I said either you or your friend enabled the sound indicator and/or removed the sound applet, which is not by default in a FRESH Lubuntu install.